# Download Sharepoint Docx file via Python office365 API

Tags: python, sharepoint, ms-word

So I have looked through all the other "download a file from sharepoint with Python" questions, but have found myself in a somewhat unique situation. Most people seem to be downloading xlsx or csv files from SharePoint, but I need to download a Word Docx file, edit it locally, and then upload it back to Sharepoint.

I can read in the file with the standard:

```
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=XXX, client_secret=XXX)
ctx = ClientContext(site_url, context_auth)

#read and write docx file to local dir to later take in as 
path = "C:/Users/username/Documents/file.docx"
output_notes = File.open_binary(ctx, "/sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents/test/word_doc.docx")
with open(path, "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(output_notes.content)
```

but this doesn't seem to work (no written file is appearing). Obviously, the read in `output_notes` is a binary, and I don't know how to turn it into a docx file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

This Github repository includes a sharepoint module with a python class designed to upload and download files and folder from and to SharePoint.

[SharePoint Class](https://github.com/Tax-Justice-Network/tjn_tools)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).